# DocuSign API - Capture when the user selects "Finish later"

Tags: docusignapi

We use DocuSign API to embed the signature process in our SAAS application. When the user clicks on "Finish Later" I would like to redirect him to a page on our side with a specific message to inform him that we acknowledged his action and that he still has to send the document before the DD/MM/YYYY for example.

Based on DocuSign API, I can't see in the [documentation](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Post%20Recipient%20View.htm) any parameters that could help me capture this (see the `returnUrl` parameter). I also have the feeling that `cancel` is sent out which we already capture to show a different page.

Do you know if it is possible and how?

Comment: Please see below - let us know if you need any additional clarification on the various events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "cancel" event that is appended to the returnURL you specify is the 'finish later' event.

Comment: Thanks! Could you confirm it is the only action that would trigger the "cancel" event?

Comment: Basically it's any graceful cancel/exit from the signing experience for a document which is not completed. So Finish Later is one option, the other (classic signing) is a small X that appears on the top right corner (DNE in new signing UI). If the document is already signed/declined/voided, but the recipient tries to view the document in this read-only state, it will result in the "viewing_complete" event.